# Append() Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to append content to an Element with append(load()), but it's not working.

```
$('#id').append(load('page.html'));
```

Is there any other way to do this? Or is there any mistake in this code?

Comment: Use only .load('page.html')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of the `.load()` method is not correct, also `.load()` method doesn't append the loaded contents, it overwrites the previous contents, you should use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` function instead:

```
$.get('page.html', function(data) {
   $('#id').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The load function actually inserts the content into the matched element. You don't have to manually append the content.

All you'll have to do is specify the element you want to populate and call the load method on it:

```
$( '#id' ).load( 'page.html' );
```

References:

- [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

The `load` method doesn't return elements that you can append, it loads content into an element. If want to append the content, append an empty element that you can load the content into:

```
var e = $('<div>');
$('#id').append(e);
e.load('page.html');
```

If the element is initially empty, so that it doesn't matter if you append or replace the content, you can just load the content into the element:

```
$('#id').load('page.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `load()` on jQuery object, call $(selector).load() The load would be undefined the way you are trying to call if it is not a user defined function.

```
$('#id').load('page.html');
```

Comment: Well that was a typo.

Comment: It would be better if down voter have given the reason

Comment: SE management discourages people giving reasons for downvoting. (I really need to find that meta page...) @Lix: The correct response to a simple, obvious typo is to edit and fix it.

Comment: @adil - in some cases yes. But in the case where someone posted an answer without proof reading the content - I'm not sure...

Comment: @Lix, I have added the description about the possible problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I don't want to encourage the FGINW problem. One should proof read their answers before posting. A spelling mistake would have been fixed - but not a code error (no matter how small).

Comment: @Lix, If one tell about the typo in code in the answer then would it be good or bad?

Comment: @Adil - the code you posted was so small - less than one line if you ask me... I think you would have seen it had you re-read the post before submitting...

Comment: @Lix, Do you mean for big code pointing typo is right and for small code pointing typo is wrong?

Comment: @Adil - with a bigger code sample, it is conceivable that someone might overlook something while considering the logic behind the code. So yes.. for more code I think I would have said something... the code you posted was so small I really didn't feel that much effort was put into the answer (hence my initial downvote - which has since been removed).

Comment: I was expecting yes or no for my question. "for small code pointing typo is wrong?" yes or no ?

Comment: @Adil - not everything is black and white... It all depends. As a high rep, veteran user I'll look at your content in a different way than I would look at a new users first post. I do expect better quality from more experienced users.

Comment: I agree every thing is not in black and white but we can try to make it. Do you mean "for person with high reputation having small code pointing typo is wrong?" yes or no?

Comment: @Adil - If you agree with me on that then we can leave this conversation as it is. I'm not going to give you a yes/no answer after we can see that we both agree there can be no single yes/no answer.

Comment: We can leave this but I belive this particular situation can have answer in Yes or No.